# SNOPT for OpenMDAO

Tags: openmdao

I am looking to purchase SNOPT for openMDAO(for AMIEGO specifically). May be I'm missing the obvious, but I have no idea where to begin. Should I get the SNOPT compiled executable built against ASL or  mex-file version or something else? I found multiple sellers who offer different formats of SNOPT. Which one is compatible with openMDAO? Also once I have it, how should I go about setting up everything with openMDAO? (I already have pyOptSparse installed)

I apologize if this type of question is not encouraged in this platform. I'm new to this and I'm completely lost.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SNOPT installation is purely a related to pyOptSparse. OpenMDAO uses pyOptSparse as is. So if SNOPT is not working in OpenMDAO, then it is because something has gone wrong with your SNOPT install in pyOptSparse itself.

One way you can test if things are working is to run the [pyOptSparse test for SNOPT](https://github.com/mdolab/pyoptsparse/tree/master/test).

You want to order a source distribution of SNOPT from [here](http://www.sbsi-sol-optimize.com/asp/sol_snopt.htm)